# Showing initialy hidden iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am loading registration page in footer as a hidden iframe (inside display: none div).

```
include(/login/pages/register.php')
```

When "register" button is clicked  - registration form is supposed to appear (but it doesn't). The problem is - the iframe initializes on BODY Load (onload="RegStartup.init(config)" inside **< body >** tag). As the registration page is hosted on a remote server I cannot change anything.  The only solution I have found is to reload the iframe when "Register" button is clicked:

```
$('.register').click( function (){

        // reloading frame to trigger init
        $( '#reg_iframe' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });

        $('.reg_overlay').fadeIn(666);
        $('#auth_popup').fadeIn(666);



    });
```

This works but the solution is rather ugly. How else can I get this working?

additional info; this problem is in Firefox only. Chrome, IE - works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the main reason the iframe is not showing up is, quite obviously, `display: none;` so  - any OTHER ways to hide iframe and then reveal it will work well. For example:

1. to use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;` OR
2. to set iframe's zero height (`height: 0%`) an, on click, to make it 100% (or 100vh)

OR to use the initial solution shown above.